CSVReader TryGetField Unescaped Quote
I am using CsvReader to parse a string similar to
var dataToParse = "US"|"10"|"0"|"0"|"45.0"|"1.0"|"Product is 1""|"1.65"|"Lb"|"10.20"|""

Since I am parsing multiple records types dynamically I am using the TryGetField(). When it reaches the unescaped quote, the TryGetField returns false like it would when it reaches the end of the record. Is there a way to determine if this is bad data vs the end of the record?
Sample Code
var parserConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  {
    Delimiter = '|',
    Mode =  CsvMode.RFC4180,
    Escape = '"'
    
  };

  using var streamRecord = new StringReader(dataToParse);
  var csvRecordReader = new CsvReader(streamRecord, parserConfig);

  while (await csvRecordReader.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
  {
    var fieldlist = new List<string>();
    while (csvRecordReader.TryGetField(iterator, out string? field))
    {
      // do something with the field here
      fieldList.Add(field);
    }
   
    // At this point, I want to know if I have reached the end of my record 
    // or if the failure is because of bad data. 
  }


Please post a [mcve]

It would be better to fix the code that's producing the CSV data so that it escapes the double-quote properly.

100% agree that fixing the code that producing the bad data is the better option but this being provided by a third party so when I get bad data, I want to return an error. Right now I am "successfully" parsing incomplete data.
